# Uploading processed Image to Azure blob using Python

Tags: python, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a processed Image to Azure Blob, what I am doing is taking two images from requests.file and uploading to blob on Azure and using these two images(file1, file2) I am generating a new Image(merged_image) but while uploading it, it always show an error i.e. TypeError: seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

My Code

merged_image = Steganography.merge(Image.open(file1), Image.open(file2))

local_file_name3 = 'merged_image.png'

blob_client1 = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=conatiner_name, blob=local_file_name3)

blob_client1.upload_blob(merged_image)

I am not finding any solutions to this...

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

For more reference check with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#download-the-blobs)